# how to get values for repeated columns

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

```
Id       account   date

101       23       01/01/2015

101       24       01/01/2015

101       25       02/01/2015

102       23       02/01/2015

103       24       02/15/2015
```

How to get the values where same id present in diff account..??

Example; 101

Comment: Do you simply want a list of Id that appear with more than one account date, or do you want the account dates that correspond to those same ids? What should the output look like?

Comment: Hi Pittsburgh,  simply want the IDs where they were in more than one account?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Group By then Check count greater than 2. Assuming that you have unique combination of ID, account and date

```
SELECT ID
FROM t
GROUP BY ID
Having count(*) > 2
```

Comment: HI piyush,  I want the IDs where they were in more than 2 accounts?

Comment: then you can use `Having count(*) > 2`.  seee modified danswer

Comment: for the same ID and same account there might be different Dates alos Piyush

Comment: First correct your sample data, and include your expected result? Right now its unclear and all mess what you  need

Comment: now you can see the id 101 in three accounts(23,24,25) and the dates for all three rows is not same.  I need to fetch that kind of IDs                                  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select id, account, date
  from yourtable
 where id in ( select id
                 from yourtable
                group by id 
                having count(*) > 1)
```

See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56c1d/1

As I said on the comments, please UPDATE your question to attend your new requirement. For your original question the answer above will solve your problem, since you asked for a new requirement you should update your question or create a new one.

Here is what you ask on the comments.

```
select yourtable.id, yourtable.account, 
       yourtable.dt, accqt.qtdAccounts
  from yourtable inner join
       (select id, count(*) qtdAccounts
          from yourtable
         group by id) accqt
          ON (yourtable.id = accqt.id)
 where yourtable.id in ( select id
                           from yourtable
                          group by id
                         having count(*) > 1 )
```

See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56c1d/4

Comment: Hi Jorge. Thank you.. But could you please suggest how to check for the accounts too... Like in how manyaccounts the member is present? Irrespective of dates...

Comment: @Gangireddy Yes, of course. But first edit your question with this new requirement. We here on SO tend to attend the objectivity of the question so it will not confund others with similar problem.